# LINQ to XML using joins

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file in the following format where `action type=0` is the default settings.

Actiontype 1 and 2 are override settings. So whenever Type 1 or Type 2 settings are available in the XML they should override the default settings.

To override the field id's of the default type=0, I am trying to do a join with the field id of override type=1, so that I can get the type=1 values and use them within my application. Howvever, the join doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to override the default values?

Type=0 is always available, but either Type=1 or Type=2 will be passed.

Is there another way to do this with reflection?

#### XML

```
<ActionTypes>
    <ActionType Type="0">
        <Field Id="Label1" Name="StartDate" ComparePreviousYear="False" CompareCurrentYear="True"></Field>
        <Field Id="Label2" Name="EndDate" ComparePreviousYear="False" CompareCurrentYear="True"></Field>
        <Field Id="Label3" Name="Cost" ComparePreviousYear="True" CompareCurrentYear="False"></Field>
        <Field Id="Label4" Name="Total" ComparePreviousYear="False" CompareCurrentYear="False"></Field>
    </ActionType>
    <ActionType Type="1">
        <Field Id="Label3" Name="Cost" ComparePreviousYear="True" CompareCurrentYear="True"></Field>
    </ActionType>
    <ActionType Type="2">
        <Field Id="Label2" Name="EndDate" ComparePreviousYear="True" CompareCurrentYear="True"></Field>
    </ActionType>
</ActionTypes>
```

#### Code

```
IEnumerable<XElement> defaultFields = from test in defaultElements.Elements()
                                        where test.Attribute("Type").Value == "0"
                                        select test;

IEnumerable<XElement> overrideFields = from test in defaultElements.Elements()
                                         where test.Attribute("Type").Value == "1"
                                         select test;

var overrideFields = from dflt in dftElements.Elements("Field")
                       join ovrd in ovrElements.Elements("Field") on dflt.Attributes("Id") equals ovrd.Attributes("Id")
                       select dflt,ovrd;
```

Comment: An unrelated tip: you don't need `.Value` in `.Attribute(...).Value` in all your comparisons. `Attribute(...)` will return a value of type `XAttribute`, and the latter has a bunch of implicit conversion operators, including to `string` - since you use string literals on the right side of `==`, that conversion will be used. The advantage, aside from being shorter, is also that conversion operators will also work on `(XAttribute)null`, producing `(string)null`, which you can compare against (or ignore) - while using `.Value` will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Pavel: All the conversions from XAttribute are explicit, aren't they?

Comment: @Jon: indeed, and I cannot edit the comment to correct that anymore :( so there needs to be a `(string)` cast there. The main point still stands though (that using conversions takes care of nulls in a much more concise way).

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, I totally agree with that part :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Attribute` here rather than `Attributes`:

```
join ovrd in ovrElements.Elements("Field")
    on dflt.Attributes("Id") equals ovrd.Attributes("Id")
```

As it is, you're comparing two `IEnumerable<XAttribute>` for equality, which will use a simple reference comaprison - which will never be true.

Comment: Thank you for your tips and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work if I have understood your requirement correctly

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");
            var defaultElements = xd.Document.Element("ActionTypes");


            IEnumerable<XElement> defaultFields = from test in defaultElements.Elements()
                                                  where test.Attribute("Type").Value == "0"
                                                  select test;

            IEnumerable<XElement> overrideFields = from test in defaultElements.Elements()
                                                   where test.Attribute("Type").Value == "1"
                                                   select test;

            var ovFields = from dflt in defaultFields.Elements("Field")
                           join x in overrideFields.Elements("Field") on dflt.Attribute("Id").Value equals x.Attribute("Id").Value
                           into g
                           from ovrd in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select (ovrd == null ? dflt : ovrd);
            foreach (var x in ovFields.SelectMany(y=>y.Attributes()))
                Console.WriteLine("{0}           {1}", x.Name, x.Value);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion using the left join worked perfectly!